# Server-Client architecture with GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, client-server

I'm writing a Whiteboard application.

Only the Client need a GUI to draw and to update drawing from other clients.

What is the best way to implement Client-side :
At first, is it preferable to split the Network and GUI components in two files because using inner classes would be too heavy ?

Now, who creates who : 
-Client Network creates the Client GUI so it knows the GUI and can update directly ?
-Client GUI creates the Client network from another file and probably implements a custom Listener listening for Server requests and updates the GUI ?

Finally, as my Server broadcast the shape sent by any client to everyone. Is it a problem if the client drawing a shape has to wait for the server reply, to draw it on the GUI ? Because it would be complicated to draw directly in the client GUI, send the shape and remove the sender from the arraylist of client when broadcasting.

Comment: You definetely need: [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Sure but MVC does not specify how to manage the files in a given language ?

Comment: Of course not, it is a model how to design network app with GUI